# Get length of characters between two matching charcaters in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

For Example if input string is "Bcoica",
the length of string between matching characters (between two c's) should return 2

Comment: have you tried anything? maybe with `indexOf`?

Comment: If there are three matching characters, do you want the distance first and last match or first and second match? For the former, you can use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`, for the latter, you can use `indexOf` twice, after slicing the string at the first match.

Comment: no need for slicing. just take the last found index plus one as start index as second parameter.

Comment: Right, that's actually a better way to do it, thanks. @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0):

You may try out as,

```js
let mystr = "Bracelet";

function distanceBetweenDuplicateCharacters(char,str){
  return str.substr( str.indexOf(char) + 1 ).indexOf(char);
};

console.log(distanceBetweenDuplicateCharacters('e',mystr));
```

Comment: The matching letter is dynamic. We have to find out which letter is matching in any string. The letter "C" is not fixed for all strings

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) with a starting index.

```js
var string = 'Bcoica',
    first = string.indexOf('c'),
    second = string.indexOf('c', first + 1);

console.log(second - first - 1);
```

Comment: The matching letter is dynamic. We have to find out which letter is matching in any string. The letter "C" is not fixed for all strings

Comment: just take a variable with the wanted letter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you can approach this problem.
Just use [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) and make a prototype with it for conveniecnce.

```js
var string = "Bcoica";

String.prototype.sizeBetween = function(startChar, endChar) {
 //we first get the position of the first char in string
  var target = this;
  if(startChar===endChar){ // if it's equal we go to the next character
    startChar = target.indexOf(startChar);
    endChar = target.indexOf(endChar, startChar+1)
  } else {
    startChar = target.indexOf(startChar);
    endChar = target.indexOf(endChar);
  }
  return endChar-startChar-1; //just return the diference between the two numbers
};

console.log(string.sizeBetween("c","c"));
```

Comment: The matching letter is dynamic. We have to find out which letter is matching in any string. The letter "C" is not fixed for all strings

Comment: Well you can simply change the c inside the call can't you ?
console.log(string.sizeBetween("o","a"));
console.log(string.sizeBetween("b","i"));
etc ...